# How to use ngRoute for routing?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am working on a project where when a user clicks on any of the two button choice, the user gets directed to a new page with a corresponding registration form. I am a front end developer and therefore am very inexperienced on the server side. I am guessing I need node routing to accomplish this, but don't know how to do this. Currently I am using the ng-view directive to load a new registration page when the user clicks a button. But like I said, this is not what I want because when the registration form appears, the 2 buttons and the original question still appear and that's not what I want. I could use ng-hide and ng-show but I decided not to because I want the user to be directed to a new page that shows the registration forms. My main page is index.html and it looks like this:

```
<html ng-app="myHome">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.8.3/ng-table.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/redirect.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script><!--This is to call Angular JS-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.8.3/ng-table.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/redirect.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="rotate">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <img src="/css/Logo_75.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <h1>WHAT TYPE OF QUOTE ARE YOU REQUESTING:</h1><br>
            <h1>DIGITAL OR SCREEN QUOTE?</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="#/digital">DIGITAL QUOTE</a></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="#/screen">SCREEN QUOTE</a></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="container">
     <div ng-view></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

My angular app or redirect.js looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myHome', [ngRoute]); 
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) { 

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: '/index.html' })
        .when('/digital', { templateUrl: '/digital.html' })
        .when('/screen', { templateUrl: '/screen.html' })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' }); 
}]);
```

where digital.html is the digital registration form and the screen.html is the screen registration form. I can provide those files if anyone wants to see them.
Please provide me with some sample code so that I can visualize whats going on. Thanks everyone for your help I greatly appreciate it.
Sincerely,
Node Clueless

Comment: does the current setup of ngRoute give errors ? what's exactly going wrong?

Comment: I can't understand how this question is related to node, I only see angular code

Comment: Why do you posted the same exact question?

Comment: I have not written any node yet. I was mentioning node because when I used Angular I realized that it will just load the view where I have the ng-view directive. What I want is that when I click the button it should direct me to another page that shows the registration form. Based on that, I am suspecting there needs to be some server side code used and since I don't know much node or back end I needed help to get started

Answer (score 0):

In a simple page webapp, the routing part is handled in the front(such as Angular in your example). NodeJS doesn't handle routing problem, but for giving the REST API interface.

So what you want is just to configure well your `$routeProvider`. Because I notice that in your route provider configuration, there is no controller for each child page. Maybe you can start with this point?